# Inverse on Matrix Returning Floating Point Exception C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a class to find the determinant and inverse of a matrix. My program can find the determinant and is able to print it out, however for the inverse part, it returns "Floating point exception". I was wondering if I could get some help on why this is happening and how to fix it. Here's my code:

```
double matrix::determinant()
{
    double det1 = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        det1 = det1 + (a[0][i]*(a[1][(i+1)%3]* a[2][(i+2)%3] - a[1][(i+2)%3]*a[2][(i+1)%3]));
        cout << "The determinant of matrix 1: " << det1 << endl;
    }

    double det2 = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        det2 = det2 + (b[0][i]*(b[1][(i+1)%3]* b[2][(i+2)%3] - b[1][(i+2)%3]*b[2][(i+1)%3]));
        cout << "The determinant of matrix 2: " << det2 << endl;
    }       
}

double matrix::inverse()
{
    cout << "Inverse of matrix 1 is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << ((a[((j+1)%3)][((i+1)%3)] * a[((j+2)%3)][((i+2)%3)]) - (a[((j+1)%3)][((i+2)%3)] * a[((j+2)%3)][((i+1)%3)])) / det1 << "\t";

        cout<<"\n";
    }

    cout << "Inverse of matrix 2 is: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            cout << ((b[((j+1)%3)][((i+1)%3)] * b[((j+2)%3)][((i+2)%3)]) - (b[((j+1)%3)][((i+2)%3)] * b[((j+2)%3)][((i+1)%3)])) / det2 << "\t";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you testing this on a matrix that has a determinant of 0?

Comment: What you should do is learn to use the debugging part of your development environment.  If run from the debugger it should stop there, let you look at the call stack and variable values, and from that you should be able to figure this out.

Comment: @Frank, no one matrix has a positive determinant and the other has a negative. however, my program doesn't attempt to even do the inverse of the negative inverse, as it stops and says floating point exception for my first matrix, which has a determinant of 6.

Comment: Does your compiler show you any warnings? Hint: what is the value of `det1` variable in the scope of `matrix::inverse()`?

Comment: I would suspect division, you have only 2 divisions are you sure det1 and det2 are not 0?

Comment: Are `det1` and `det2` class variables? It looks like you write to local variables in `determinant()` but use the class ones in `inverse()`.

Comment: @DmitriChubarov When I went to debug it, there was a warning saying "source file is more recent than executable". Wouldn't the value of `det1` still be the same as previous in `matrix::determinant()?`

Comment: @user3655463 Yes I am positive that det1 and det2 have values. With the matrices I created det1 = 6 and det2 = -9.

Comment: @dlasalle Yes they are class variables. I rewrote them within my `matrix::determinant()` though

Comment: No `det1` would not be the same in `inverse()` as in `matrix::determinant()` because in `matrix::determinant()` you declare them anew as local variables. This leaves your instance variables unaffected by the call to `determinant()`.

Comment: @dlasalle Okay thanks I understand now! So now my inverse matrices are returning int values, even though I called for `double matrix::inverse()`. How do I go about fixing that??

Comment: @DmitriChubarov Yes I understand now! Thanks for the help! Do you know how to get my inverse matrix values to be doubles? I called `double matrix::inverse()` so I'm not quite sure why it's giving me int values.